# JAXPConfigurator is that some kind of a SAX parser?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Looking at some old code that uses JAXPConfigurator.configure(Reader, false) and not really sure what does it do; thanks.

Comment: Please add the fully qualified name of the class.

Comment: Looks like org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.configuration.JAXPConfigurator

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation here: http://proxool.sourceforge.net/api/org/logicalcobwebs/proxool/configuration/JAXPConfigurator.html

It appears that `JAXPConfigurator` is just a wrapper around a JAXP parser that is used to load and parse a proxool XML configuration file.

Comment: I am missing the main concept here, specifically, does the XML file in conjunction with the configurator builds a class dynamically?